# Haskell multi-line `let` in `ghci`

Tags: list, haskell, ghc, multiline, ghci

I'm in `ghci` and find that the following works:

```hs
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

... but this doesn't work:

```hs
let bar = ["a",
           "b",
           "c"]
```

... nor does this:

```hs
let baz = ["a"] ++
          ["b"] ++
          ["c"]
```

The same error is provided when I try to compile it as a file, so it's not something that comes from being in `ghci` vs using `ghc`.

The error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:3:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GHCi you can use `:{ :}` for multiline expressions. For example:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let bar = ["a",
Prelude|            "b",
Prelude|            "c"]
Prelude| :}
```

The `:{ :}` keeps GHCi from evaluating your code after the next newline and throwing errors at you because it is not a complete expression.

Note also that the `let` is not needed for top-level definitions. In a normal Haskell source file you would just write:

```
bar = ["a",
       "b",
       "c"]
```

Furthermore in newer GHCi versions (8.0+) you don't need the `let` either.

Comment: What about if I were to compile the code with `ghc` (not `ghci`)

Comment: In a source file you don't need `:{ :}`. You just write normal Haskell. `:{ :}` are just there to keep GHCi from evaluating your code and throwing errors at you after the first newline.

Comment: That multi-line code doesn't compile in `ghc` either.

    let foo = ["a", "b", "c"]

    let bar = ["a",
               "b",
               "c"]

    let baz = ["a"] ++
              ["b"] ++
              ["c"]

    main = print foo

(for example)

Comment: For a top-level definition in a source file you wouldn't write the `let`. Just `bar = ...`

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include the details in your comment? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Scoobie I did.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that if you are using the latest GHC (version 8.0 and above) you don't need the `let` for top level definitions in GHCi anymore, which makes `:{ :}` even more convenient.

Comment: @jpath Indeed. I wrote the comment (in my head) before your edit :-)